# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

На строке

```
context = new ApplicationDbContext();
context.Clients.Add(item);
```

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured
>   for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the
>   DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the
>   application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also
>   ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions
>   object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for
>   DbContext.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        }

        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
```

**Обновлено**

после добавления

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) { optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"); }
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 0.
>
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(string
>   connectionString, int currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, out
>   string keyname, out string keyvalue)

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplicationCore-42a4ac05-477c-4ea7-b286-87423170b48a;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

2:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) { optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplicatio‌​nCore-42a4ac05-477c-‌​4ea7-b286-87423170b4‌​8a;‌​"); }
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 108.
>
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(string
>   connectionString, int currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, out
>   string keyname, out string keyvalue)

3:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) { optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplicatio‌​nCore-42a4ac05-477c-‌​4ea7-b286-87423170b4‌​8a"); }
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
>   error occurred. Во время запуска экземпляра LocalDB произошла ошибка:
>   ошибка запуска процесса SQL Server. )
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo,
>   bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, Вы используете .net Core?

Comment: да...............

Comment: Добавь в свой ApplicationDbContext это: protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your_connection_string");
        }

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: а напрямую пропиши: Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplicationCore-42a4ac05-477c-4ea7-b286-87423170b48a;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

Comment: теперь 
`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'trusted_connectio‌​n'.

System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary<string, string> parsetable, string connectionString, bool buildChain, Dictionary<string, string> synonyms)`

Comment: `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) { optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplicatio‌​nCore-42a4ac05-477c-‌​4ea7-b286-87423170b4‌​8a;‌​"); }`


`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 108.

System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(string connectionString, int currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, out string keyname, out string keyvalue)`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58052/discussion-between-gromanev-and-codename0082016).

Answer (score 0):

Need to add overload OnConfiguring:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    readonly string _connectionString;

    public ApplicationDbContext (DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext > options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext (string connectionString) : base()
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

Call:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext ("DefaultConnection"))
{
   //db.
}
```